# RoR, Multiple request calls API, need optimization please

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, optimization, instagram

I'm trying to work with [Instagram's API](http://rubydoc.info/gems/instagram/0.10.0/frames) and I'm able to make requests and such, but I'm trying to make requests with search [tags](http://rubydoc.info/gems/instagram/0.10.0/Instagram/Client/Tags) using `tag_recent_media`.

I believe they don't have support for multiple queries? Please someone correct me if I'm wrong. In my controller, I have multiple queries and I'm doing it like so:

```
@cats = client.tag_recent_media('cats', options = {:count => 60})
@dogs = client.tag_recent_media('dogs', options = {:count => 60})
@birds = client.tag_recent_media('birds', options = {:count => 60})
@snakes = client.tag_recent_media('snakes', options = {:count => 60})
```

I think this is making a huge amount of request doing it like this?

I'm using each variable (i think thats what you call these? with @s, variables?) and putting it into an array, and sorting it in my view file:

```
    <% (@cats+@dogs+@birds+@snakes).sort{|a,b| -(a.created_time <=> b.created_time)}.each do |media| %>
        <span>
        <img src="<%= media.images.thumbnail.url %>">
        </span>
    <% end %>
```

Does Ruby on Rails have some kind of way of making easier requests?